# Media Field not showing up in Site Column list

Tags: 2010, content-type, site-column

I have installed Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise with SP1. I created a new Web Application, and in it a Publishing Site collection. I created a new Content Type and am trying to add a new column of type Media Field. I have never used this field before, but came across it while doing some searches. Why is this Column Type not showing up?

[Here](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=YncPcNzQl54C&lpg=PP1&hl=pt-BR&pg=SA11-PA75#v=onepage&q&f=false) is where I first found out about Media Field

> Simply extend the Content Type associated with the specific page layout in use by including a new Column of type Media Field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SharePoint 2010 - Publishing features enabled, you should see "Rich Media data for Publishing" when you start creating a new Site Column.

Comment: Hello Ashish i had used PublishingPageImage Column in custom pagelayout it is working fine now i want to use same for video where user can add video like publishing page image field so is it possible to do that...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have Publishing features activated, then go to Site Settings > Site Columns.
The  Media Field only shows un when creating columns from the Site Settings area. If you try to add the column from withing the list instance itself it won't show up.